# Checking checkboxes on webform via URL query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a registration form with several classes from which one can choose more than one (checkboxes). There is also a corresponding fee that is popped into a textbox for each class.
One also must select one membership category (radio buttons).

Each checkbox item has a unique ID and value. They are all named "courses[]".  When the form is submitted, the values are sent to the registration desk via a php script that writes to a database and sends email (and all the courses' titles are under "Courses").

Here's the issue: 
I want visitors of the website to be able to click on a link next to the class they want. The link is a URL query string that pre-fills the regform with the default membership category and also checks the checkbox next to the class. But so far it's only working for the radiobutton option of membership and not for the checkbox classes. I need to modify or replace the code to accommodate these checkboxes, but I need help.

The URL query string I am using looks like this (not a real URL):

https://domain.edu/summer.php?membership=Current&courses=ClassTitle_12345

Here's the pertinent script from the form page [loads after DOM]:

```
function getUrlParameters() {
    var urlQuery = location.search;
    urlQuery = urlQuery.replace('?', '');

    if (urlQuery.indexOf('&') == -1) {
        checkPreselectedMembership(urlQuery);
        checkPreselectedMembership(urlQuery);
   } else {
        var params = urlQuery.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            checkPreselectedMembership(params[i]);
        }
    }
    total();
}

function checkPreselectedMembership(param) {
    var split = param.split('=');
     if (split[0] == "membership") {        
       if (split[0].match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{1,20}$/)) { // only allow numbers, letters, and the underscore
            document.getElementById(split[1]).checked = true;

        }
    }
}
```

And here a snippet of the HTML:

```
<input name="courses[]" type="checkbox" id="class01"  onClick="classFees();total();"    value="ClassTitle1_12345" title="Check to select course">
Class Title 1</td>
$<input name="class01_fee" size="10" type="text" readonly title="class fee">

<input name="courses[]" type="checkbox" id="class02"  onClick="classFees();total();" value="ClassTitle2_34568" title="Check to select course">
Class Title 2</td>
$<input name="class02_fee" size="10" type="text" readonly title="class fee">
```

I hope that I have been clear with my questions. Thank you.

Comment: So the link next to the class takes them to the registration form page with the checkbox for that class pre-selected? Also: `if (location.search.length > 0) { var params = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); } else { /*nothing chosen*/ }` ... and ... Why are you calling `checkPreselectedMembership(urlQuery)` _twice_ `if (urlQuery.indexOf('&') == -1)`? Plus: if this is going to a PHP page then the PHP code can check the boxes, don't do it in javascript.

Comment: Show your PHP code! ;) There, you can access the GET parameter which are in the URL and check the radio and checkbox easily.

Comment: Yes, this link would take them to the regform page and the checkbox next to that class would be preselected. I didn't write the existing javascript, so I don't know why that call is there twice. I'm not a coder, and this form has been cobbled together by myself and others, so I'm sure it has its flaws. I'm open to scrapping the javascript for a php solution, but that's way over my abilities.

Comment: Looking at this form, I'm going to need to stick to modifying the existing javascript. I just made a modification to it and changed the URL query string and it worked.